# Raspberry Pi - Captive Portal without internet display html page

Tags: raspbian, web-server, server, captive-portal

### I need to create a **Captive Portal** with a Raspbery Pi.

I would like to do that:

1. The client connect to the WiFi (without password)
2. Automatically will auto-redirect to a webpage, just to read a message

**IMPORTANT** the HTML page, can be modified just if you are the administrator.
(Sorry for my English)

I have done a lot of research on the internet, but I have not found any tutorial that explains how to make a captive portal, without using the internet. Currently I have used a software called "Info-Blaster" created by Zavvio LLC. It would be perfect to create something like "info-blaster" but for free.
I am a studente can somebody help me?

Comment: What research have you done? I have seen several such project on github.com and several "tutorials" is easy to discover with a search engine.

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional information. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/117115/edit) your qustion and put it there. And please click this link: [captive portal](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=captive+portal)

Comment: Please read, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I found some tutorials on the internet but many of them are either outdated or don't work without the internet.
I really need some help.
Keep in touch, this is my email (if you need) salvoferro16@gmail.com